# Spring Boot : Log File in current date directory and rollover

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging

My requirement is to print logs in current date directory and logs needs to be rollover in current date directory with below conditions :

1. Either hit max file size
2. Or date has changed

So today date is 16/07/2019 so directory structure should be

16_07_2019/fde.log (current log)

16_07_2019/fde.1.log (due to max size)

16_07_2019/fde.2.log (due to max size)

15_07_2019/fde.log (yesterday log)

15_07_2019/fde.1.log (yesterday log due to max size)

my logback.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true">

    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>

    <appender name="FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/VVV/AA/%d{yyyy_MM_dd}/fde.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>/VVV/AA/%d{yyyy_MM_dd}/fde.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>2MB</maxFileSize>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{MM:dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] [%level] [%logger{36}] - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Instead of creating current date directory it is create `%d{yyyy_MM_dd}` directory. I am not sure why?

Also, Is this xml looks fine based on my requirement?

Using SpringBoot : 2.0.5 version

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<file>/VVV/AA/logs/fde.log</file>
<rollingPolicy
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <!-- rollover daily -->
    <fileNamePattern>/VVV/AA/logs/fde-%d{yyyy_MM_dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
    <maxFileSize>2MB</maxFileSize>
</rollingPolicy>
```

As in roll only over the file name rather than log file directory.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't like this solution... but it works...

1. Declare a "**timestamp**" property before starting Spring Boot.

> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>   System.setProperty("timestamp", Constants.ISO_YYYY_MM_DD_FORMAT.format(System.currentTimeMillis()));
>   SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MainConfig.class);
>   app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
>   app.run(args);
> }
> ```

2. In application.properties

> logging.path=${folder.deploy}/logs/${timestamp}

3. In logback.xml, you import the property

<springProperty scope="context" name="LOG_PATH" source="logging.path" />

And off you go...

I still think there has to be an application.properties ONLY solution...